# Why are trees appearing on objects with glossy materials?

Tags: rendering, node-editor

[image]

I’m not sure What it is? I’m trying to get a glossy shade to building in my scene as soon as I put roughness to zero I see these trees in glass. I have no trees in my scene anywhere, background is black. Even when I render I see these trees. How can I get rid of them and still keep my glossy building material.

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Answer (score 3):

Your viewport shows a default HDRi to illuminate your objects.
It will not appear in your render.

You can toggle *Scene World* to use your *World color* instead.

[image]

Comment: I will try hope it works thx for yr help.

Answer (score 2):

Zero roughness will give you a mirror basically and the trees you are seeing are probably from HDRI image that's being used in the material preview view or if you have one loaded in your world settings. May I ask why you took a picture of your monitor instead of just screen capping and posting that I find this so odd?

Comment: Thx for your reply. Well that’s the thing I don’t have any HDRI in my world setting if any it should be galaxy which I uploaded but change my mind and went for complete black background. I just used my phone it was easy yeah I should’ve just do the screen shot. I do odd things. I will take yr advise clear all previews and see if that works. Thx again.